# A good LAN messaging and file-sharing application

Tags: software-recommendation, file-sharing, lan

Presently I use iptux for sending messages and sharing files over my hostel LAN, but the interface isn't quite convenient and the files sent/received don't reach the destination completely a lot of times.

Is there a better LAN messaging and file-sharing application on Ubuntu? I don't intend to use samba as I need to send messages too.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the open source project Openfire, its a jabber protocol server so you will be able to setup your own private network and still use popular applications like Pidgin as it uses the XMPP protocol.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp

Checkout the plugin page to see how extensible it is and if it meets your needs.

It's java based so install should be a breeze.

Comment: I am not able to figure out how do I share a file using this, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The libpurple based instant messengers [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) (Linux & Windows) and [Adium](http://adium.im/) (Mac OS) have support for the XMPP-based [Bonjour](http://www.apple.com/macosx/technology/bonjour.html) chat protocol which is server-less on the local network and supports file transfers¹.

¹ Apparently file transfer doesn't work in all situations with all clients e. g. with iChat.

Comment: File transfer is crucial in my case.

Comment: Since file transfer seems to work between libpurple clients on all platforms, you could just use those instead of iChat or others.

Answer (score -2):

The lan messaging software Output Messenger will fulfill all your interoffice business communication needs.

http://www.outputmessenger.com/

This team chat app offers a lot of instant messaging features including One-to-One Chat, Group Chat, File Transfer, Remote Desktop Sharing, Voice Call, Group Video Chat and Conferencing, Off-the-Record Messaging and Communication Restriction etc.

Comment: Two problems: 1) It requires a server to be installed in Windows only; 2) It's a commercial (paid) closed source software. And the language suggests you're actively promoting the product... Without disclosing you're perhaps a sales person? The textbook definition of SPAM although the reviewers didn't notice the faint smell of BS.

Comment: Really, I am not promoting that messenger. We are using it in our concern for interoffice communication that impressed us so wished to suggested it here. That's all!!